# html fitting text in between two images that resize

Tags: html, css, text, center, image-resizing

Basically I want the text to always be centered in the middle. With one image  on either side that resize depending on how large the page is to take up all the white space. This is what I have so far.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
        <img style="float: left; width: 33%; margin:20px 0 0 0;" src="img/pulse.gif"/>
        <img style="float: right; width: 33%; margin:20px 0 0 0;" src="img/pulseR.gif"/>

        <h1 style="display:inline; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; width: 33%;">Safety</h1>
    </div>
```

I would like to remove the width: 33% and for the images to resize to fit the space. Keep in mind it needs to be forced to stay on one line.

Thanks

Comment: It seems you are looking for a css table. Although flex boxes or columns might work too, but my money is on a table.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Wrap the images inside a container and make it flexible. Put the text between the image containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table` and `table-cell` for `display`, or just classic html `table`.

There is example using `table` and `table-cell` for `display` (there is added extra `divs` for images and header) :

```css
.container
{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.container div
{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.container img
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"/></div>
    <div><h1>Safety</h1></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap images inside div containers like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <div class="left"> <img src="img/pulse.gif"/></div>
        <h1>Safety</h1>
<div class="right">
    <img src="src="img/pulseR.gif"/></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uv85304v/